# in angularjs how to update DOM from factory data fetch

Tags: angularjs-service

after successfully insert record into the database. I want the list to be updated.

basically, when starting the app, list will be populated with data from controller like this :

```
DisplayTrackingCode().then(function (result) {
  $scope.items = result;
});
```

then, if i insert new record from `.factory`. List is not updated, i need to change to other page or restart the app to see the new changes.

```
.factory('AddTrackingCode', function() {
return {
get: function(track) {
    console.log(track);
    var db = openDatabase('mydb','1.0','db',2 * 1024 * 1024);
    db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO trackingcode (code, name) VALUES ("'+track.code+'","'+track.name+'")'); 
    });
}
}
})
```

then, how do I update the list again automatically ?

Answer (score 0):

i solve it by using `$broadcast`

right after inserting record, i made a `$broadcast` in the controller

```
$scope.$root.$broadcast('updating');
```

then, in another controller that handle the DOM that I need to change :

```
$scope.$on('updating',function(){
  DisplayTrackingCode().then(function (result) {
  $scope.items = result;
});
});
```

this will update the DOM.